# Return difference of two 2D arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I have 2 2d arrays and I would like to return all values that are differing in the second array while keeping the existing dimensions.
I've done something like `diff = arr2[np.nonzero(arr2-arr1)]` works to give me the differing elements but how do I keep the dimensions and relative position of the elements?

Example Input:

```
arr1 = [[0 1 2]  arr2 = [[0 1 2]
        [3 4 5]          [3 5 5]
        [6 7 8]]         [6 7 8]]
```

Expected output:

```
diff = [[0 0 0]
        [0 5 0]
        [0 0 0]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about the following:

```py
import numpy as np

arr1 = np.array([[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]])
arr2 = np.array([[0, 1, 2], [3, 5, 5], [6, 7, 8]])
diff = arr2 * ((arr2 - arr1) != 0)

print(diff)
# [[0 0 0]
#  [0 5 0]
#  [0 0 0]]
```

EDIT: Surprisingly to me, the following first version of my answer (corrected by OP) might be faster:

```py
diff = arr2 * np.abs(np.sign(arr2 - arr1))
```

Comment: Your original answer using np.sign was the fastest for me. Even using np.abs to fix the issue that I assume you changed it for. `diff = arr2 * np.abs(np.sign(arr2-arr1))`

Comment: @nemi Yes, I realized the result was not what you wanted when the difference is negative. Anyway glad it worked!

Answer (score 2):

If they are numpy arrays, you could do

```
ans = ar1 * 0
ans[ar1 != ar2] = ar2[ar1 != ar2]
ans
# array([[0, 0, 0],
#        [0, 5, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0]])
```

Without numpy, you can use `map`

```
list(map(lambda a, b: list(map(lambda x, y: y if x != y else 0, a, b)), arr1, arr2))
# [[0, 0, 0], [0, 5, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

Data

```
import numpy as np

arr1 = [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]]
arr2 = [[0, 1, 2], [3, 5, 5], [6, 7, 8]]

ar1 = np.array(arr1)
ar2 = np.array(arr2)
```

Comment: I had a similar approach. You could use `np.zeros(arr2.shape)` or `np.zeros_like(arr2)` for building array with zeros. Nice one.

Answer (score 2):

I am surprised no one proposed the [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) method:

```
diff = np.where(arr1!=arr2, arr2, 0)
```

Literally, where arr1 and arr2 are different take the values of arr2, else take 0.

Output:

```
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 5, 0],
       [0, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: You posted a minute before I was editing my answer with `np.where`. I can roll back my edit if you want.

Comment: @Ch3steR no, don't worry ;) actually even get my vote

Answer (score 1):

### [`np.copyto`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.copyto.html)

You can check for inequality between the two arrays then use [`np.copyto`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.copyto.html) with [`np.zeros`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html)/ [`np.zeros_like`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.zeros_like.html).

```
out = np.zeros(arr2.shape) # or np.zeros_like(arr2)
np.copyto(out, arr2, where=arr1!=arr2)
print(out)

# [[0 0 0]
#  [0 5 0]
#  [0 0 0]]
```

### [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

You can use [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and specify `x`, `y` args.

```
out = np.where(arr1!=arr2, arr2, 0)

# [[0 0 0]
#  [0 5 0]
#  [0 0 0]]
```